# Limit scrollbars to content area when static header/footer are present

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, box

There is this example for a web page with static header and footer:
[Site Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20140620132337/http:/www.dkngstudios.com/company#faq)
(when looking at this webpage, please remove the transparent archive.org header by clicking on the red "X" top right)

My question is, is it (easily) possible to limit the scrollbar to the actual (scrollable content) area -- in other words, the scrollbar should not extend over the static header and footer (like it does now).

[Here is a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7S4Xx/48/) showing the same: scrollable content with static headers and footers where the scrollbar goes over header and footer, but should be limited to the content box:

```
#content {
width: 1024px;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 60px 0;
height:calc(100% - 120px);
}
```

Here is an example of the current implementation:

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color:#ff00ff;
    margin:0px auto;
}
.wrapper {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
.container {
    width:1024px;
    margin:0px auto;
    height:100%;
}
header {
    width: 1024px;
    height: 60px;
    background: red;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}
#content {
    width: 1024px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 60px 0;
    height:calc(100% - 120px);
    background-color:#fff;
}
footer {
    width: 1024px;
    height: 60px;
    background: red;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <header></header>
        <div id="content">
            <p>HELLO</p>
            <p>HELLO</p>
            <p>HELLO</p>
            <p>HELLO</p>
            <p>HELLO</p>
            <p>HELLO</p>
            <p>HELLO</p>
            <p>HELLO</p>
            <p>HELLO</p>
            <p>HELLO</p>
            <p>HELLO</p>
            <p>HELLO</p>
            <p>HELLO</p>
            <p>HELLO</p>
            <p>HELLO</p>
            <p>HELLO</p>
            <p>HELLOWEEN</p>
        </div>
        <footer></footer>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello David, I voted to close this question, because it is unclear and show no effort on your side to solve a problem. You should create a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and include your code within the question to receive good answers. If you want to point to a site and say "I want this too", you will need to hire someone. Best of luck.

Comment: @David.P in your given website link. you want like when user scroll content will not shown beside the transparent header right?

Comment: Thanks. Added a jsfiddle link.

Comment: Another example is [here](http://aktuell.de.selfhtml.org/artikel/css/footer/beispiel6.htm). Also there, the scrollbar should be limited to the scrollable content div.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a scrollable content pane, by using: `overflow: auto;` on `#content`.
Here is an altered version of your css to help you with your current problem:

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color:#ff00ff;
}
.wrapper {
    width:1024px;
    height: inherit;
}
.container {
    margin:0 auto;
    height: inherit;
}
header {
    height: 60px;
    background: red;
}
#content {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    height:calc(100% - 120px);
    background-color:#fff;
    overflow: auto; 
}
footer {
    height: 60px;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <header></header>
        <div id="content">
            <p>HELLO</p>
            <p>HELLO</p>
            <p>HELLO</p>
            <p>HELLO</p>
            <p>HELLO</p>
            <p>HELLO</p>
            <p>HELLO</p>
            <p>HELLO</p>
            <p>HELLO</p>
            <p>HELLO</p>
            <p>HELLO</p>
            <p>HELLO</p>
            <p>HELLO</p>
            <p>HELLO</p>
            <p>HELLO</p>
            <p>HELLO</p>
            <p>HELLO</p>
            <p>HELLO</p>
            <p>HELLO</p>
            <p>HELLO</p>
            <p>HELLOWEEN</p>
        </div>
        <footer></footer>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the jsFiddle as well: http://jsfiddle.net/7S4Xx/271/

Comment: Thank you very much Nico for fixing my question and for providing the solution!

I only changed the wrapper width to 100% and added comments to the code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6vg9ez87/3/), in order to understand what everything does.

Could you maybe fill in the CSS comments such that I can learn why you did the different changes, and why it was not sufficient just to add "overflow: auto" to the content div?

Thank you again

Comment: There are a lot of way to solve the task you provided. You could have used `position: fixed` like you did before or `flexbox` or what so ever. So I can not provide you a best practice. I choose this way to don't disturb your provided environment too much. I'd suggest to grab your browsers developer tools and play around. Just compare your and my solution. P.s `width: 100%` will not be needed, as block elements will fill the `width` of it's parent item by default. Good luck.